# Es mi primer código, quiero compartirlo y saber cómo creen que puedo mejorarlo

Tags: python, while, random, integer

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Python, y escribí un programa juego que elige un número al azar de 0 a 100, y debes adivinarlo. El juego da pistas y notifica si el input no es un número. Ahora lo terminé, y creo que el conocimiento hay que compartirlo, por lo que vine a postearlo y consultar cómo podría mejorarlo o continuar avanzando en programación.

El código es:

```
import random
def numero ():
    a = random.randint(0,100)
    g = False
    while not g:
        try:
            b = int (input("que numero crees que es?"))
            b = int(b)       
            while a != b:
                if b<a:
                    print(str (b) +" " + "es mas chiquito que el numero que pense"+" ")
                else:
                    print(str (b) + " " + " es mas grande que el numero que pense"+" ")
                b = int (input("que numero crees que es?"))
            print ("ganaste")
        except ValueError:
            print("lo que has ingresado no es un numero"+" ")
        if a == b:
            g = True
            print("gracias por probar mi juego")
```

La finalidad de la vida es compartir el conocimiento.

Comment: Dicho lo de arriba, yo usaría `isdigit()` para quitar el try/except y `f-strings` para hacer las strings más legibles.

Comment: Un consejo que te ahorra infinitos dolores de cabeza: prefiere las  expresiones en positivo, No digas "while not g;", Invierte el uso de "g" para que digas "while g:".

Comment: Es mejor usar el patrón "while True:" y salir del ciclo usando "if condicion: break". Te ahorras una variable y la intención se expresa más claramente.

Comment: Las concatenaciones de strings son costosas en tiempo y RAM. Usa las opciones de formato (f-string, operador % o impresión por partes) cuando sea posible y razonable.

Comment: Tienes operaciones repetidas ("input") que son y hacen lo mismo. Es malo, pues si necesitas cambiar la operación (por ejemplo, con un nuevo mensaje), debes hacerlo en dos partes. Reordena el código para hacer cada cosa una sola vez.

Comment: Tienes operaciones innecesarias ("b = int(b)"), pues ya "b" está convertido a entero en la linea previa.

Comment: Las operaciones al fin de un while ("print ("gracias ...") deberían estar después del while por claridad. Asi se expresa con claridad que no es una operación repetitiva.

Answer (score 1):

Juntando todas las recomendaciones, asi luce mejor:

```
import random

def numero ():
    a = random.randint(0,100)
    while True:
        try:
            b = int (input("que numero crees que es, entre 0 y 100? "))
            if b < a:
                print(b, "es mas chiquito que el numero que pense")
            elif b > a:
                print(b, " es mas grande que el numero que pense")
            else:
                print("ganaste!")
                break
        except ValueError:
            print("lo que has ingresado no es un numero")

    print("gracias por probar mi juego")

numero()
```

Nota:

La indicación de Saelyth de usar `isdigit()` es igualmente válida, pero favorezco el uso de `try-except` ya que simplifica el código de los "casos buenos", en este caso, cuando `b` es entero.